# Set explicit initialization for enum in Typescipt

Tags: angular, typescript, enums

How can i set explicit initialization for the below `enum` in `typescript`?

```
enum BloodGroup {
    OPositive = "O +ve", 
    ONegative = "O -ve", 
    APositive = "A +ve", 
    ANegative = "A -ve", 
}
```

Need something like (Knew this doesn't work),

```
enum BloodGroup {
    OPositive = "O +ve" = 1
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? That isn't really how enums are meant to be used.

Comment: I want to show the enum for "OPositive" as "O +ve". Do you have any other way? I'm new to typescript

Comment: maybe with heterogeneus enums you could do something:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#heterogeneous-enums

Comment: @iamCR your original string enum should work fine. `BloodGroup.OPositive === 'O +ve'`

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#string-enums

Comment: @Collierre the enum should start from 1. Where can i set that?

Comment: @iamCR why do you need it to have a 1 value? String enums aren't intended for that. It might help if you post the other bits of your code that require a number for this enum.

Comment: In default it starts with 0 and i want it to start from 1.

Comment: @iamCR, he's not asking about why you want it to start at 1 vs. 0, Collierre is asking why does this have to be numeric at all?

Comment: @iamCR, enums are either numeric, string, or a mix of numbers and strings. When enums are all numeric, each numeric value can be mapped automatically to a strings, but those strings are the names of the enums themselves -- you can't have them map to anything else.

Comment: I was about to use the id in the API/DB, so i felt it didn't want to have 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Typescript, [enums are represented as values on an object](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#enums-at-runtime). Unlike Java-based enums, each entry is not its own object instance and entries are not kept in an array that would otherwise give a convenient "number" (which in Java is also zero-based and automatically assigned without overrides). Given those, it is impossible for a native enum to have both a string value and an integer value.

You could keep those values separately, though:

```js
enum BloodGroup {
    OPositive = 1, 
    ONegative = 2, 
    APositive = 3, 
    ANegative = 4, 
}

function labelForBloodGroup(group: BloodGroup) {
  switch (group) {
  case BloodGroup.OPositive:
    return "O +ve";
  case BloodGroup.ONegative:
    return "O -ve";
  case BloodGroup.APositive:
    return "A +ve";
  case BloodGroup.ANegative:
    return "A -ve";
  }
}
```

[link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYOwrgtgBAQgNgewQEwOICcFgA5QN4BQUxUA8gAoIDOAlgC40BuwUAvFAIwA0URJpAOWABzAIYNmbKACYefYgEFKtCS3YBmOSSgKhY1VIAscgL4ECAMzAgAxgwQgocUQCNgcAGIJ08JGkw4ABTCAdgAXLCIKBhY2ACU+HxUAO70NgAWUMGhCYTENqJULL7RoQB0FNT0TMBh8lDowHRg6I4ARKRQANTMbQDcfAVFkX4xOBV64jV12o3NrVAdUAC0vQP5hcVR-rFlSlWqMyRzLe0K3WuDmyOlu7oiU8xHxCcLbeerwP18ZmZAA)